# Python requests i get connection reset errors

Tags: python, python-requests

I use requests, in order to get some images out of a webpage.
But after a while, I get a connection reset error. How should I alter below code?
I believe somehow the `requests.Session()` object in Python requests library allows to use persistent connection, could do the job.

```
import csv
import requests

with open('urls.csv') as csvfile:
    csvrows = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in csvrows:
        filename = row[0]
        url = row[1]
        print(url)
        result = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        if result.status_code == 200:
            image = result.raw.read()
            open(filename,"wb").write(image)
```

Error I'm getting:

```
lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 417, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1426, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1166, in _raise_ssl_error
    raise SysCallError(errno, errorcode.get(errno))
OpenSSL.SSL.SysCallError: (104, 'ECONNRESET')
```

Comment: Most likely the site you're scraping has detected you're scraping it and is closing the connections. You can probably prevent this by 1) letting a few seconds elapse between each request and 2) making sure you're sending HTTP request headers similar to what a browser would send.

Comment: so how the above could be achieved? How the code should be made? do i have to do both? or just the second could do the job?